# Concerns about using XSLT Load method

Tags: c#, xml

I have an application whose design is as follows:

1. There is hot folder into which an xml file is dropped whihc is picked up by this application, App1
2. An XSLT is applied to the incoming xml which tranfroms it to another xml
3. For the XSLT work the XSLT Compileted transform class is used calling the Load method
4. The result of the transform is used by App1
5. A new instance of App1 is started for every file being dropped into the hot folder

Another application manages watching the hot folder and sending the xml to App1.
All the above steps except #4 are part of App1.

Couple of days back App1 stopped working. Checking the log file showed that the Load method of XSLT Compiled transfrom class was failing. Re-installing App1 seem's to take care of it for now.

I am sure this will come back.

Found some interesting stuff [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2011/09/26/effective-xml-part-3-didn-t-you-say-xslcompiledtransform-was-fast.aspx) regarding XSLT Compiled transform.
The suggestion in that blog is to call the Load method just once and re-use the output in successesive calls. 
I don't know how to do that considering the way App1 is build.
The second option is to use XSLTC to create C# class and use that as a reference. Here too the App1 ends up calling the Load method passing the Type as param.

What can I do to avoid calling the Load method all the time? 
Does this mean I have to write a 2nd App, App2, to do that and somehow sync it with App1?

Seriously I don't want to go that way.

What are my other options to deal with this?

Comment: To avoid calling XmltCompiledTransform.Load() per each request one could use a single instance of App1 and spawn a new thread per request. Threads(unlike processes) share global variables.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this or provide a link where I can get reference. I haven't programmed Threads before so would like to know something about them before getting to wrtie some code.

Comment: First you should post the stack trace for the exception.  Also, its nice to see the code of the method that failed.